# how to setup akka actor as rabbit mq listner in xml

Tags: rabbitmq, akka, actor

I am creating events and sending them to RabbitMQ  and added a listener class to receives the event and process them.

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
                               message-converter="messageConverter"
                               concurrency="50">
        <rabbit:listener ref="monitoringMbean" method="startReceving" queue-names="eventQueue"/>
    </rabbit:listener-container>
```

Now I want create a AKKA Actor to do this job. My question is how can I define my AKKA actor as rabbit listner in my context xml?

Answer (score 1):

If you write on Scala then you can use Akka RabbitMQ client: https://github.com/thenewmotion/akka-rabbitmq

Better option is to use Akka-stream: http://typesafe.com/activator/template/rabbitmq-akka-stream